# Using diodes to isolate RV body from chassis

Tags: diodes

I have a [camera & monitor](https://www.visionworkscameras.com), specs 12 0r 24VDC in, max three amps.  I want them to be usable when vehicle ignition/accessory is on, or when RV body is powered, or both.  But I don't want to break or contaminate the normal isolation.  I have four [1N5406](https://www.rlocman.ru/i/File/dat/Diodes/Diodes_Rectifiers_Single/1N5404.pdf) diodes.  One should be sufficient for three amps, but since I have no other use for them, I might as well engage in a little “overkill.”  I worked in electronics for ten years, and even taught it for three, but I changed careers in 1988.  So I figure it might be wise to confirm my design with the folks here on SE.  Will the design I have pictured work?  (Clouds represent complicated systems for generator/charging/utility power, etc.)  I’d like to use what I have on hand instead of running to the far side of the city to buy something else.
[image]

Comment: Diodes don't isolate.

Comment: Use a bistable relay 5 terminals and the output ie camera will be connected to ignition or rv..

Comment: That would certainly work, but I’d have to wire up a line to pull/release the relay.  And I’d have to turn on the monitor again each time it switched.

Comment: There are special IEC (or perhaps UL) rated Zener diodes for the very purpose you describe for use in boats for not degrading zinc anodes on said boats due to small potential differences between mains ground and local actual ground.

Comment: The anodes are not zinc, and nothing is connected to "local actual ground" unless the tires are conductive.  I thought Zeners were for controlling voltage.

Comment: I would put those diodes in series, not parallel.  They are 600V blocking 3A diodes, a single one can handle the current.  However, in the case where one fails short, if they are in series then you're still protected.  In parallel one shorted diode will make its buddy ineffective.

Comment: @WGroleau use the ignition supply to trigger the relay - it’s there anyway. So no need for an extra cable.

Comment: good point, @KyleB

Comment: Don't know what @JRE means by "diodes don't isolate."  With a direct connection instead, everything that's supposed to be off when the ignition is off would be on whenever coach lamps and appliances are on.  And vice versa.

Comment: "isolate" has a specific meaning in electronics, and diodes don't do it.

Comment: And neither comment on "isolate" tells me what word you would prefer me to use. n Not that it matters because you already know what I meant.

Comment: "Isolate" in electronic-speak is generally taken to mean "Galvanic Isolation"... i.e. a connection between two systems with NO actual metallic connection.  For example, a simple transformer is an "isolation" device.  So is a relay, and an optoisolator.   Basically a system where the energy is transmitted through air, not a solid material.  Diodes don't "isolate" in that regard.  It's just semantics -- Your system concept is logically sound.  I'm not really sure what word you'd use for this ... "Reverse polarity protection" maybe.

Comment: That said, I personally would indeed seek to do something 'isolated' as there is some hazard involved with mixing systems like this.  Relays are an ideal device for the purpose.  If you have time and a little extra $$$ I'd do that.  Difficulty in obtaining electronic components ("I have to drive across town") isn't a thing since the internet.  You can get anything you want delivered to your door in a couple days.     The whole business model of retail electrical components is pretty much gone (Seen a Radio Shack lately???)

Comment: I'll think about a relay, but every time power switches, the monitor has to be manually turned on again.  Minor irritation.